# SubSelect na mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando criar um subselect na mesma coluna, eu tenho que usar uma linha da coluna para voltar um novo valor da propria coluna..
segue meu codigo sql

```
SELECT `idUnidadeOrganica`, `NmUnidadeOrganica`, `idUOSuperior`, 
    (SELECT `NmUnidadeOrganica` FROM `unidadeorganica` WHERE  `idUnidadeOrganica` = `idUOSuperior`), 
    `SgUF` 
FROM `unidadeorganica`;
```

No caso estou tentando voltar o nome NmUnidadeOrganica que tem o seu idUnidadeOrganica igual ao idsuperior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.idUnidadeOrganica, u.NmUnidadeOrganica, u.idUOSuperior, u2.NmUnidadeOrganica 
FROM unidadeorganica AS u 
LEFT JOIN unidadeorganica AS u2 ON u.idUnidadeOrganica = u2.idUOSuperior;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer join na mesma tabela, sem problemas:

```
select fil.idUnidadeOrganica as id_filha,
    fil.NmUnidadeOrganica as nm_filha,
    mae.idUnidadeOrganica as id_mae,
    mae.NmUnidadeOrganica as nm_mae
from unidadeorganica fil, unidadeorganica mae
where fil.idUOSuperior = mae.idUnidadeOrganica;
```

Ou você pode fazer esse mesmo select usando inner join:

```
select fil.idUnidadeOrganica as id_filha,
    fil.NmUnidadeOrganica as nm_filha,
    mae.idUnidadeOrganica as id_mae,
    mae.NmUnidadeOrganica as nm_mae
from unidadeorganica fil
    join unidadeorganica mae on
        fil.idUOSuperior = mae.idUnidadeOrganica;
```